# Is there a way to communicate with the PS3's bluetooth connection in Java

Tags: java, bluetooth, playstation3

I've searched extensibly but haven't found anything useful. I am wondering if it would be possible to create a remote control app for a smartphone. Some older forum posts I've read said that it is not, but these posts were several years old.

Comment: I think that the linux versions for the ps3 have a way to communicate with the controllers. I may be wrong though.

Comment: Hmm... interesting I'll look into this. Thanks.

Comment: It most be possible or there wouldn't be any non-Sony remote controls. i.e.: blulink remote

Comment: Are you asking *how to work with Bluetooth using Java* or are you asking *what's the protocol/messages that the PS3 uses, when communicating over Bluetooth*?

Comment: Well wondering if it's even possible to communicate with the ps3 via bluetooth. One post I read somewhere said that the ps3's security limits what you can do with the bluetooth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.  It's simply a Bluetooth link.  There are a number of third-party peripherals (Logitech makes one) that allow you to connect to the PS3 via Bluetooth.  That said, you may be limited in what you can do.  I would imagine you'd be limited to the functionality that they define through a specific "controller" API.  What that API is, you'll need to do some research.  All that you need to do is find a Java library for Bluetooth connections or use something like Android's built in Bluetooth API.  From there, you need to figure out what messages you want to send.  Does that answer your question?

Comment: Hmm... I'm reading some things that suggest Logitech and those companies can do it because they have a Playstation development license. I can't even find anything saying someone has successfully paired a blackberry with ps3, my PS3 won't discover my Blackberry.

Answer (score 1):

As already stated... the PS3 uses the Bluetooth HID profile.

Sony also seem to have a restriction on who can use the PS3's bluetooth protocol, as I've noticed, only official Sony products are able to access the PS3's internal bluetooth.

You may also notice, that any wireless peripherals normally come with a bluetooth USB dongle... I don't see why there would be any reason you can't pair this to another bluetooth device, and control the PS3 that way.

I think your best bet is to forget about trying to connect to the PS3 internal bluetooth (unless you're a great hacker) and to get busy with an external USB bluetooth dongle.

Answer (score 0):

The PS3 uses the Bluetooth HID protocol for communication, the phone and the application will have to have the HID profile (Device role) to talk to the controller. 
In addition the PS3 will be using proprietary HID reports to talk with the PS3 controller.

So it is possible if you can do the following :- 
Get access to a phone that supports HID device , and you need to also get API to access , get access to the HID reports used by PS3.

So it is possible with a lot of hacking :)